# Popup Window not display when edit or add rows although I write it on asp.net blazeor?

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on asp.net blazor dot net core version 7 . I face issue Popup Window not display when

press edit button to edit the rows on table

so why not display and How to fix it .

I add Popup Window on my code below but it not display so what I do to fix it .

what I try as below :

ServersNames.razor component

```
@page "/Servers/ServersNames"
@using UC.AppRepository.Core.Entities
@using UC.AppRepository.Core;
@using UC.AppRepository.UI;
@using System.Text.Json
@using System.Text.Json.Serialization
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration config
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@using System.IO
@using BlazorInputFile



<table class="class table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ServerId</th>
            <th>Server Name</th>
            <th>Server Type</th>
            <th>Options</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var serv in ServerName)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@serv.serverID</td>
                <td>@serv.server_Name</td>
                <td>@serv.server_Type</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" @onclick="(()=> editClick(serv))">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M12.146.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-10 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.168.11l-5 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.65-.65l2-5a.5.5 0 0 1 .11-.168l10-10zM11.207 2.5 13.5 4.793 14.793 3.5 12.5 1.207 11.207 2.5zm1.586 3L10.5 3.207 4 9.707V10h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.293l6.5-6.5zm-9.761 5.175-.106.106-1.528 3.821 3.821-1.528.106-.106A.5.5 0 0 1 5 12.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.468-.325z" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>

                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    @ModalTitle
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Server Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="server_Name" />

                    <span class="input-group-text">Server Type</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="server_Type" />

                  
                    @if (ModalTitle == "Add Server")
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CreateClick">
                            Create
                        </button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="UpdateClick">
                            Update
                        </button>
                    }
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and to display data on list :

```
@code
{
    public class ServerNamesClass
    {
        public int serverID { get; set; }
        public string server_Name { get; set; }
        public string server_Type { get; set; }

    }
    private IEnumerable<ServerNamesClass> ServerName = Array.Empty<ServerNamesClass>();

    private string ModalTitle;
    private int serverID;
    private string server_Name;
    public string server_Type;


 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await RefreshList();
    }

    private async Task RefreshList()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, config["API_URL"] + "ServerNames");
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        ServerName = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<ServerNamesClass>>(responsestream);


    }
 private void editClick(ServerNamesClass serv)
    {
        ModalTitle = "Edit Server";
        serverID = serv.serverID;
        server_Name = serv.server_Name;
        server_Type = serv.server_Type;



    }
    private void AddClick()
    {
        ModalTitle = "Add Server";
        serverID = 0;
        server_Name = "";
        server_Type = "";



    }
```

see picture of issue
[image: issue when edit or add rows]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one page demo to show you one way to hide/show the dialog.  I've used one of the standard Bootstrap dialogs.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="modal @this.modalDisplayCss" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick=this.Close></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @onclick=this.Close>Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.Save>Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=Open>Show Dialog</button>
</div>
<style>
    .show-dialog {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
@code {
    private bool _modalVisibility;
    private string modalDisplayCss => _modalVisibility ? "show-dialog" : "";

    private Task Open()
    {
        _modalVisibility = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task Close()
    {
        _modalVisibility = false;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task Save()
    {
        _modalVisibility = false;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

PS - there are several Dialog implementations you could use [including a simple one of mine].  Search - Blazor Modal Dialog.